# CkFinder recreating thumbnails every time

Tags: ckfinder, ckfinder3

When viewing the list of uploaded images, the request to view the thumbnail first deletes all the thumbnails for that image, then checks to see if they exist, then re-creates them; even if the image hasn't been changed.

I'm using a custom back-end to Azure Blob storage, and this behavior is causing our entire site to stall when scrolling through large directories of images. How do I prevent it? (Either the deleting or the regeneration).

Comment: Same problem here..

Comment: @JJaun That sucks. I lodged a ticket with CkSource, but they wouldn't look at my code and I couldn't look at their code so the ticket went nowhere. (I did try decompiling their DLLs but couldn't get anywhere with that either.)